# .NET XSD Documentation Generator

Tags: .net, documentation, xsd, documentation-generation

I'm looking for an XSD Documentation Generator for .NET. Please, provide any references.

> Note: If it is available with source
>   code that would be much better choice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xs3p` XSLT stylesheet will convert your XSD files into nicely formatted HTML documentation. It's free, 100% XSLT source - go grab it here:

http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/

Marc